# set a cell value with an arraylist using Apache POI

Tags: java, web-applications, arraylist, apache-poi

I'm trying to create an Excel file using Apache POI library. In this file I want to create a table which contains the data from a database table. The content of this table is save on an ArrayList object which contains a model.
My question is: how can I set the value of a cell having an arraylist?

Comment: You mean you want to iterate over the objects in the array list creating a cell for each value or you have multiple values to put in each cell?

Comment: I want to iterate the arraylist and I want to put one value on each cell, but every object of the arraylist has multiple values.

Comment: use foreach iterator and loop set values to the cells by incremented the cells.

Comment: I have solved using a foreach loop. Thanks!